# Adding events to google calendar from my app

Tags: android, gdata-api

I have the code. No errors in eclipse. But in the emulator, I'm getting "Application has stopped unexpectedly" error. I have done a lot of research but I'm not able to get rid of this. All I want the app to do is to add events to my google calendar.

The code snippet:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // Set up the URL and the object that will handle the connection:
   URL postUrl = null;
           try {
                   postUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xyz@gmail.com/private/full");
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }

   CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
           try {
                   myService.setUserCredentials("xyz","xyz123");
           } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }

   EventEntry myEntry = new EventEntry();

   myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test event"));
   myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Working!!"));

   Person author = new Person("It's me", null, "me@home.com");
   myEntry.getAuthors().add(author);

   DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-07-20T15:00:00-08:00");
   DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-07-20T17:00:00-08:00");
   When eventTimes = new When();
   eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
   eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
   myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);

           try {
                   EventEntry insertedEntry = myService.insert (postUrl, myEntry);
           } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ServiceException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
```

Is it anything to do with the code or the manifest?

Comment: Do you have a goolge calendar installed already?

Comment: No, I'm making an app from which I can set tasks and appointments from the app to the google calendar directly. I need not install any google calendar nor is this anything to do with the inbuilt android calendar

Comment: If you don't have an google calendar installed in your device then how will you set events to it.Google calendar is an app which you have to install in your device before you can set events to it